# Inserting data to redshift using python

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into amazon `redshift` database , the rows included in a list of tuples which looks like this:

```
my_rows=[(1, 0.0, 0, 0.0, 2010188534, 1816780086, 1113834, '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17'), (1, 0.0, 1, 0.0, 2010188536, 1816780086, 1119396, '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17'), (1, 0.0, 2, 0.0, 2010188538, 1816780086, 1119398, '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17'), (1, 0.0, 3, 0.0, 2010188540, 1816780086, 1123612, '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17'), (1, 0.5, 0, 0.0, 2010188542, 1816780102, 1086852, '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17'), (1, 0.5, 1, 0.0, 2010188544, 1816780102, 1087014, '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17'), (1, 0.3, 2, 0.0, 2010188546, 1816780102, 1089224, '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17'), (1, 0.3, 3, 0.0, 2010188548, 1816780102, 1089348, '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17'), (1, 0.3, 4, 0.0, 2010188550, 1816780102, 1122564, '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17', '2018-03-07 09:40:17')]
```

Some columns may contain `None`

I'm inserting them row by row into `Redshift` database this way:

```
    cur = con.cursor()
    columns_names=("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8","c9","c10")
    insert_reference=len(my_rows[0])*"%s,"
    values_references="("+insert_reference[0:-1]+")"
    for row in my_rows:
      cur = con.cursor()
      insert_query="INSERT INTO "+table+" "+columns_names+" VALUES "+values_references+";"
      cur.execute(insert_query, row)
```

The problem is that when I run this code, it blocks on the first row without raising any error. So, my questions are : 
Is it normal that it takes so much time to insert one row ? If not is there some error in my code ? Is there some efficient way to that ?

Can i get some help please ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: this method will be very very slow - how many rows are you hoping to insert? how often?

Comment: I want to insert about 3000 rows

Comment: one off - or how often?

Comment: In fact, now I'm just doing a test to say whether data fits into database, but later, I'll be ingesting data once every 15 minutes

Comment: Avoid using the INSERT command to insert single rows into Redshift. You should be using the COPY command. See: [Amazon Redshift Best Practices for Loading Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading-data-best-practices.html)

Answer (score 1):

The process you should follow:

1. write your data in csv format to an s3 folder, ideally gzipped
2. run a redshift copy command to import that data into a temporary
   table in redshift
3. run redshift sql to insert that data into your table

That will run fast, is the correct & recommended way and will be scaleable.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your answer. I have data in aws s3 in JSON format, do i have to use a Lambda function to convert the past and the furtur files into csv format ?

Comment: The Amazon Redshift COPY command can also [COPY from JSON Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html).

Comment: plus - if you want another option - you can define an external table in redshift (spectrum) to access that json data.

Comment: In fact it'is a little bit more complicated, my JSON is structured this way : `{table: "x", action: "insert", row:{c1:1, c2:"a"}}{table: "x", action: "delete", row:{c1:1, c2:"a"}}` so it needs to be processed before copying files into database , and Besides I need data to be copied automatically in real time , which as far as I know the copy command don't

Comment: you could also consider aws kinesis